# MAMP emails working sporadically

Tags: php, email, mamp

I'm trying to test the mailer capacity of a site built in Jekyll, so I'm using MAMP (free version) (I'm on Yosemite, no recent updates). However, I'm having trouble with inconsistent results. Last week, everything was working and I was getting emails. Six days ago, with the same code, it wasn't working (network showed a 200 OK, but no emails were arriving). Three days ago, working (working so well that all my test emails from six days ago poured into my inbox at once). Now, broken again (again, 200 status). I didn't make any changes in the code between working and not-working.

I'm not very familiar with MAMP, but I don't understand why this would work sometimes, but not always. Nothing in the php_error.log, and I've tried closing and restarting the MAMP server to see if that would clear it.

I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar experience, but perhaps I'm not using the right search terms. & I know sometimes mail can get caught up in the server, but three days seems a bit extreme.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

If you really need, I can show code, but it's pretty standard (adapted from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form), and since it works at least occasionally, I'm assuming this is more of a comprehension difficulty than actual bad code.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it either. You might want to use formbucket or a similar service.

Comment: @john-conde: I did review that answer, and found it very helpful in getting the mailer working initially. This question is about the fact that the code has not changed, but for some reason, only works sporadically. Thank you, though!

Comment: Things outside of your code and server are probably at play. That answer addresses those issues, too.

Comment: (Thought I'd update this question, for anyone else who comes across it - @JohnConde was right in that there were definitely other factors at play. My MAMP is still sporadic about getting emails over to the recipient, but once we went live and PHP was all set up, emails began functioning perfectly.)